# Lineinfile and escaping special characters

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

My intention is to find a specific group in my hosts file, and then append an IP address after it. My hosts file looks something like this

```
[create_new_ecarews]
    *blank*

[ecarews]
 10.10.10.100
```

I'm trying to insert a new IP, 10.10.10.101 under [ecarews]. But with the following code, it ends up in [create_new_ecarews]

```
lineinfile:
  path: /etc/hosts
  insertafter: "{{ item.insertafter }}"
  line: "{{ item.line }}"
with_items:
  - { line: "10.10.10.101", insertafter: '\[ecarews\]' }
```

This is the result:

```
[create_new_ecarews]
 10.10.10.101
[ecarews]
 10.10.10.100
```

This is the desired result

```
[create_new_ecarews]
    *blank*
[ecarews]
 10.10.10.101
 10.10.10.100
```

How do I escape / match [ecarews] so that insertafter puts the ip address under [ecarews]?

Comment: The code in your question works as you expect - after correcting `lineinefile` to `lineinfile`. Are you sure you copied the code you wanted to?

Comment: Sorry im doing it from a console, so I cannot copy/paste. So that was just a transposition error on my part, I have "lineinfile" correct in my code.

Comment: But as I said, then the code from the question gives the desired result.

Comment: You are correct, I ran it with "line: 10.10.10.101" hard coded as seen above, but when I run it with how its actually written in my code, "line: "{{ ip_address }}" I get the results I described. I thought my issue was the "insertafter" criteria but it seems like my ip_address variable may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is, you cannot use lineinfile and use the same "line" but in different insertafter criteria in a playbook.

So what I did was for my 2nd and 3rd lineinfile call, I just appended "xxx" and "zzz" to the end of the IP address, and followed up with two replace commands (searching for "xxx" and "zzz" to be replaced with "") to "clean up" the workaround.